# When I tried localizing the strings were not visible in the app

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp, localization, uwp-xaml

In xaml file, I defined the button using this code

[xaml page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wR9u.png)

And in the "Resources.resw" file I defined it like this. This file is in a different class library.

[resources.resw page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYjDz.png)

But the string is not visible in the app. If the Resources.resw is in the same project which xaml file is created in this issue doesn't occur. However I cannot keep it in the same project and has to move to another class library.

This is how the files are defined,

C:\Users\annes\Desktop\localization\UWP\Main\WinApp\View\UserControl\URLUserControl.xaml
C:\Users\annes\Desktop\localization\UWP\Main\WinAppUtil\Strings\en-US\Resources.resw

How can I resolve this? Is there any other alternative ways?

I think this issue occurred as the class library namespace didn't refer in the xaml file. However I have added the class library dependency to the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to document [Load strings from a Class Library or a Windows Runtime Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest#load-strings-from-a-class-library-or-a-windows-runtime-library), the resource identifier of such a string usually takes the form **LibraryName/ResourcesFileName/ResourceIdentifier**.A library can get a ResourceLoader for its own resources.

For your scenario, you can use `ResourceLoader` to load string, or use resources directly in xaml.

```
var resourceLoader = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("<YourClassLibraryName>/<ResourcesName>/NextContent");
this.NextButton.Content = resourceLoader.GetString("Content");
```

---

```
<Button
      x:Name="NextButton"
      Margin="0,0,0,0"
      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
      Click="NextButton_Click"    
      x:Uid="/<YourClassLibraryName>/<ResourcesName>/NextContent" 
      FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
```

---

```
<data name="NextContent.Content" xml:space="preserve">
   <value>Next</value>
</data>
```